# Java, getting object from map iterator and then invoking methods?

Tags: java

I have a map and this contains objects, lets say of type 'Apple'. I currently have an iterator but the only thing I seem to be able to call is the getKey and getValue. getValue seems to return the memory address of the actual Apple object, but i wanted to be able to do Apple a = Map.Entry.getValue()

i can only seem to get the key and memory address :s

```
Iterator it = ApplesMap.entrySet().iterator();     
while (it.hasNext()) {         
    Map.Entry entries = (Map.Entry)it.next();         
    System.out.println(entries.getKey() + " = " + entries.getValue());
    //Apple a = entries.getValue(); 
}
```

Comment: "i can only seem to get the key and memory address :s" :)

Comment: If your map contains entries from some key to an instance of apple, entry.getValue() returns the actual apple. If your print statement shows something like an address in memory, your Apple class should override toString() to print something meaningful.

Comment: You should use generics.

Comment: It's not the memory address, but the `hashcode` of that object.

Comment: @asgs from the Object.hashCode() javadocs: *This is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer, but this implementation technique is not required by the JavaTM programming language*

Comment: @Sean thanks for that javadoc quote. Never actually read it.

Comment: ah ok, so if i was able to get the hashcode of the object I couldnt understand why eclipse wasn't allowing me to select any of the Apple's methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way if you're using JDK 6:

```
for (Apple apple : applesMap.values())
{
    // process apple here.
}
```

Comment: Is this a 'lesser' method than using iterators? Why do we need iterators?

Comment: @James This is a shortcut that uses an iterator internally, it's possible for all Objects that implement [Iterable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html)and it's explained [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)

Comment: @James yes this is called a [`for-each`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) loop introduced in JDK 1.5 and iterators are an older way to achieve what you've done.

Answer (score 1):

Try casting the value

```
Apple a = (Apple) entries.getValue();
a.beDelicious();
```

Comment: All other answers are better than this one, yet this gets the only upvote? Upvoting all others for balance...

Comment: it was first, so I guess that's the reason.

Comment: @Sean feel free to downvote if the quality of answer is bad. I'll take it like a man.

Comment: @Bala R - the answer is correct. So no downvote. But others are better :)

Comment: @James - because it is more verbose and it is not compile-time safe.

Comment: @James you should be using generic collections as that would  give you type safety.

Comment: @Bala no, this is not a bad answer. You are directly answering the question, correctly. But all other answers adress the problems in the question itself :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is ancient code. Use Generics and for-each loops.

```
Map<String, Apple> map = // create map here
for(Map.Entry<String, Apple> entry : map.entrySet()){
    Apple thisIsAnApple = entry.getValue();
    String andThisIsTheKeyThatLinksToIt = entry.getKey();
}
```

BTW:

- if you just want the keys, use
  `map.keySet()`
- if you just want the values, use
  `map.values()`
- use `map.entrySet()` only if you need
  the complete mapping

Comment: but you can't upvote your own.. so a little balance from me :)

Answer (score 1):

Use generics:

```
Map<String, Apple> map = ....;
```

if you need the key:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Apple> entry : map.entrySet()) {..}
```

if you don't need the key:

```
for (Apple apple : map.values()) {..}
```

Since you had a sub-question in one of the comments: Under the hood the for-each loop uses the `Iterator`. Every `Iterable` class is eligible for a for-each loop. But you are not bothered with operating the iterator - it is operated automatically for you. An `Iterator` is still useful if you want to call `remove()` on it.

Comment: Can you just clarify, why is this generics? I thought on generics you use 'E' and 'T' notation etc? :)

Comment: @James - you use E and T in the declarations (`Map<K,V>` for example). But when using them, you use types.